# How to run macro over cell selection instead of ActiveCell

Tags: excel, vba

Hello I want to run a macro "with commandbutton" over a selection of cells instead of a single cell.

The code shown below works but for a single cell, however I want it to run over a selection.

P.s. I am only showing 1 If statement in the code there are 100 of them.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

x = ActiveCell.Value * 2

If x > 0 And x < 200 Then
y = 290 
End If 


ActiveCell.Offset(0,1) = y
```

I want the the macro to run over a selection of cells.

I've tried: `Selection.Offset(0,1)` but that didn't work

Comment: What sort of selection? Row, column, a block?

Comment: This is the bible ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba

Comment: Please not that *"didn't work"* is no useful error description.

Comment: Primarily in a single column but. I want it to a selection applied by dragging the mouse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following sub. Modify as your need.

```
Sub RunSelection()
Dim cel As Range
Dim x As Double

    For Each cel In Selection
    x = cel.Value * 2
        If x > 0 And x < 200 Then
            cel.Offset(0, 1) = 290
        End If
    Next cel

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you elaborate how to implement multiple if statements?

Comment: Thank you this "modification" code worked, however I'd like to ask how I can clear it's memory after it runs the code through all cells?